# Why Doesn't This Java Code Skip Lines with #?

Tags: java, file-io

I'm a bit of a newbee but I'm trying to allow an external .txt file that is read by a Java script be able to have some comments in the beginning of the file so others can easily edit it and add more to it.
But if the file contains # (the sign designated for a line that is a comment) it just returns the error that there is a "Format Error in file" (the IOException - so it is getting past that first "IF"...)
Can someone help?

Here's the portion of the code that deals with commenting lines out of the .txt file being called earlier in the script:

```
   while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    line = line.trim();
    if (line.length() < 1 || line.charAt(0) == '#') { // ignore comments
     continue;
    }
    final String[] parts = line.split("=");
    if (parts.length != 2) {
     throw new IOException("Format error in file "
       + JLanguageTool.getDataBroker().getFromRulesDirAsUrl(getFileName())
       + ", line: " + line);
    }
```

The input.txt file breaks it at the first line:

> ```
> #This is a Test
> ឲ្យ|ឱ្យ=អោយ
> កំពស់=កម្ពស់
> កម្នាញ់=កំណាញ់
> ```

And here is the actual error:

> ```
> Caused by: java.io.IOException: Format error in file
> ```
>
> file:/D:/Documents......./coherency.txt,
>   line: #This is a Test
>       at rules.km.KhmerSimpleReplaceRule.loadWords(KhmerSimpleReplaceRule.java:165)
>       at rules.km.KhmerSimpleReplaceRule.loadWords(KhmerSimpleReplaceRule.java:82)
>       ...33 more

And the stack trace error:

> Caused by: java.io.IOException: Format
>   error in file
>   [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@1cb2795
>   at
>   km.KhmerSimpleReplaceRule.loadWords(KhmereSimpleReplaceRule.java:
>   169)

Comment: which line did the exception thrown?

Comment: Could you post a minimal input file with which the problem can be reproduced? Also, you could put debug printouts into the code to check what's going on, e.g. printing out each line, its first char and whether the `continue` branch or the rest of the code was executed.

Comment: Possible whitespace before #?

Comment: Try debugging, print the line in order to know what it has which made it skip the `if` statement.

Comment: @ Lukas Eder I don't think we could load it this way without re-doing the whole script - currently it is being loaded with the following (getFileName contains the location of the text file): wrongWords = loadWords(JLanguageTool.getDataBroker().getFromRulesDirAsStream(getFileName()));

Comment: @Tobiask, in theory `line.trim()` should have taken care of that, but who knows, there *might* be some other character there...

Comment: @Tobiask: no, `trim()` would trim both leading and trailing.

Comment: Are you sure that the error is that the line starting with a hash is getting picked up as invalid and not that something else in the file is malformed?  What testing have you done?  I'm curious because this code *looks* right and I'm wondering if something else is the culprit.

Comment: @tanyehzheng I added the error that Java gives to the original question - it errors because the line has more than 2 parts (there is no "=" sign on the comment line)

Comment: @templatetypedef This code works in other languages (which is weird - the code is a modification of Romainian for Khmer), and if I remove the comments from the txt everything works fine, so that makes it seem like it is only an issue of the comment code

Comment: It may be a code point issue if you're talking about non-ASCII languages. What does codePointAt(0) give you on that line?

Comment: @Nathan- Can you give us the exact line that's breaking this?  Have your program print out the line that causes the error so that we can see an example of a test case that causes a failure.

Comment: @templatetypedef The line the breaks it is this: if (parts.length != 2) {
                throw new IOException("Format error in file "
Because the comment line gets through, and therefore breaks the script because it has no "=" sign which is used to signal a line split (therefore it only has one part, which throws the error).

Comment: @Nathan, he means the *input line* from the txt file, not the code line :-)

Comment: @Peter and  templatetypedef Ah, sorry - here's the first line from the input.txt that breaks it: #This is a test comment

Comment: "# This is a test comment" is not the same as "#This is a Test"

Comment: @Stephen Denne yes you are right, I've been messing around with the files as I go back and forth, trying to see if anything makes it work - I've edited the original to match the error (as it was when the error occurred)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There may be a UTF-8 Byte Order Mark in front of your first visible character. Most Editors will not show these characters since the only predict the encoding of the content and Java doesn't remove the UTF-8 byte order mark(unlike for UTF-16 and 32). If there really is an UTF-8 BOM you'll have to remove these three bytes yourself.

For more details see Java-Bug [6378911](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6378911).

Comment: ah, that would make sense - let me look into this.

Comment: Crazy - that was it!  Thank you so much!

Comment: Also [Wikipedia on the UTF-8 BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte-order_mark#UTF-8)

Answer (score 4):

This should have worked unless there are white spaces.
You can try this code.

```
if (line.trim().startsWith("#") { // ignore comments
   continue;
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what makes this different from what's already there?  That is, what case will this return true where the existing code does not, or vice-versa?

Comment: @templatetypedef - Yeah it is pretty much same, but little bit more readable IMO.

Answer (score 2):

That should work unless the `#` isn't actually the first non-whitespace character on the line (or you have a non-comment line somewhere with either no or more than one `=` in it).

I can only suggest you show us the entire exception which will include the actual offending line in it. You might also want to make it:

```
+ ", line: [" + line + "]");
```

so you're *sure* there's no leading or trailing spaces. In addition, output `line.codePointAt(0)` in the exception as well - it may be a language/wrong-Unicode-code problem.

You might also consider making your code more flexible to allow comments at the ends of lines as well. That's a simple matter of stripping out everything from the first `#` to the end of the line before the trim, and will allow things like:

```
password = xyzzy # super sekrit sauce from zork
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems correct at first...
I can see several options:

1. You can [read the Properties file](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.Reader%29) properly if it is actually a properties file.
2. You have an error in a line following the comment.
3. The `#` is not the first character of that given line.

A stacktrace and an input file might help...

Comment: Thanks - I added the stacktrace and input file to the original question

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
    line.indexOf('#') == 0
```

Or you could try:

```
     line.substring(0,0).equals("#")
```

Or show the stack trace and find the actual answer.

Comment: I'm a bit of a newbee, but here's what I came up with the stacktrace: Caused by: java.io.IOException: Format error in file [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@1cb2795 at km.KhmerSimpleReplaceRule.loadWords(KhmereSimpleReplaceRule.java: 169)

Comment: @Nathan - You should put that in your question so it can be formatted in a nicer way.  But it sounds like the problem was the UTF-8 character before the #.  Wierd.